# 802.11 encapsulated Pings not seen in Wireshark monitor mode

Tags: wireshark, wifi

I have a very basic setup to understand 802.11: Netgear router/AP (no "backside" connection to internet), Ubuntu laptop "client" and a KaliLinux box "sniffer" running wireshark in monitor mode.  I start a ping from client to the AP, and it replies fine, sending/receiving 1/second.  However, the sniffer doesn't detect anything different from no pinging. I ran the setup for 30 minutes with the client idle (no pinging) and see lots of QoS Data and Null packets (272 data / 158 null from client to AP; 13 data / 0 Null from AP to client).  Then I did the same while the client was pinging the AP (72 data / 39 null from client to AP; 56 data / 0 null from AP to client).... less packets when pinging.  ... I am using a capture filter to show only client i/o : ether host mac_of_client

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  I'd expect an 802.11 "radio" to pick up anything in the air, and with a capture filter specific to the client, to see ANYTHING going/coming from the client.... but I only see these occasional QoS and Null packets, which must be background maintenance packets (not needed as much while pinging is going on). Thanks!

Comment: nowadays most "networks boxes" including routers are switches and no longer hubs, and don't copy any packet not belonging to their exact port of destination. The hubs used to copy everything to all ports. Could it be because of that? And you likely should ask on "super user" instead of this programming Q&A place...

Comment: @B. Go keep in mind that this is a 802.11 (i.e. wireless) question. Agree that this question should be moved, but the upstream network infrastructure, whatever it is, is not going to limit traffic.

Comment: Found a problem (but not a total solution): The Kali Linux in monitor "radio" mode is still apparently blocking the packets that are the ICMP pings. When I switched around client-sniffer so that the sniffer is now the Ubuntu box (and the client now the KaliLinux box), every 1 second I now see a QoS Data and QoS Null from the client to the AP ... however I don't see the AP's response back to the client. (I'll post this in Super Users eventually)